# Посмотреть значение регистров через отладчик C::B

Tags: отладка, codeblocks

Недавно я увидел, что в MS Visual Studio 2008 можно посмотреть значение регистра eax добавлением его в watches-лист. Можно ли сделать подобное в Code::Blocks? Можно ли вообще просматривать содержимое адресов памяти, обращаясь конкретно по адресу?

Code::Blocks 16.01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В CodeBlocks можно просматривать как регистры, так и память. Но не через `Watches`, а в отдельных окошках.

Окошко с регистрами включается через: `Debug -> Debugging windows -> CPU Registers`

Окошко с дампом памяти - через: `Debug -> Debugging windows -> Memory dump`

[image: CPU Registers и Memory dump]

Просматривать память можно указав либо непосредственный адрес, либо адрес переменной (либо саму переменную, если она является указателем), либо регистр (его значение интерпретируется как адрес). На скриншоте показан дамп для регистра `$eax`.

Размер дампа можно так же выбирать в диапазоне от 16 до 4096 байт.

Comment: Кстати, в **CodeLite** можно просматривать всё то же самое, что и в **CodeBlocks**, плюс можно добавлять регистры в `Watches`.